# Calculating surface Integral over the unit ball for a vector field

Tags: multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral, surface-integrals

I am trying to do the following exercise:

Let $B=\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3: x^2+y^2+z^2=1\}$ be the unit ball.

Calculate the surface integral of $f(x,y,z)=(x^3,y^3,z^3)$ over the surface of the unit ball.

Since f is a vector field, I need to use the "surface Integral for vector fields" definition.

But first I need a parametrization of the unit ball.

I decided to use the parametrization:

$\phi (u,v)= \left(\begin{array}{c} \cos(u)\cos(v) \\ \sin(u)\cos(v) \\ \sin(v) \end{array}\right)$
for $0 \leq u\leq 2 \pi $ and $-\pi/2 \leq v \leq \pi/2$

to keep it clean let $K:=\{(u,v) \in \mathbb{R}^2:0 \leq u\leq 2 \pi ,\, -\pi/2 \leq v \leq \pi/2\}$

Now the surface integral is:
$$\int_{\phi} \langle f,n\rangle=\int_K \langle f(\phi(u,v)),  \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial u} \times \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial v} \rangle d(u,v)$$

In this case:
$ \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial u} \times \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial v} =\cos (v) \phi (u,v)$

and

$f(\phi(u,v))= \left(\begin{array}{c} \cos^3(u)\cos^3(v) \\ \sin^3(u)\cos^3(v) \\ \sin^3(v) \end{array}\right)$

Thus,
$$\langle f(\phi(u,v)),  \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial u} \times \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial v} \rangle=\cos^4(u)\cos^5(v)+\sin^4(u)\cos^5(v)+\sin^4(v)\cos(v)$$

The last step seems to be to calculate the integral:
$$\int_K \cos^4(u)\cos^5(v)+\sin^4(u)\cos^5(v)+\sin^4(v)\cos(v) d(u,v)=
\int_{-\pi/2} ^{\pi/2} [\int_0 ^{2 \pi} \cos^4(u)\cos^5(v)+\sin^4(u)\cos^5(v)+\sin^4(v)\cos(v)du] dv =\frac{12 \pi}{5}.$$

Questions:
Are my calculations correct (the way I calculate it)?

Another way to do a parametrization of the unit ball would be to solve $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ (locally) for $z$ and use $\phi_1 (x,y) =\left(\begin{array}{c} x \\ y \\ \sqrt{1-x^2-y^2} \end{array}\right)$  and $\phi_2 (x,y) =\left(\begin{array}{c} x \\ y \\ -\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2} \end{array}\right)$ as a parameterization.

In this case, do I need to do the surface Integral for both parameterizations  and sum them up? (if not, how?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach and the final result are both correct. By the [divergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem), this surface integral, which is the flux of the vector field $f$ through the surface of the unit sphere, can also be obtained as
$$\begin{align}
\iiint_{\|x\|\leq 1} \text{div}(f)\,dxdydz&=\iiint_{\|x\|\leq 1} 3(x^2+y^2+z^2)\,dxdydz\\&=3\int_{0}^{2\pi}d\theta\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin(\phi)d\phi\int_{0}^1\rho^4 d\rho=\frac{12\pi}{5}.
\end{align}$$

Comment: thank you very much